# Get value from what another function already got as `input`

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get a value from another function (input) in Python?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def xxx(self):
        self.a = int(input("enter a value :"))
    def yyy(self):
        self.xxx()
        print (self.a)

obj = MyClass()
n = int(input("choose a number : "))

if (n == 1):
    obj.xxx()
elif (n == 2):
    obj.yyy()
else:
    print ("error")
```

The problem is that when I choose number 2, it asks me to enter my value again. But I want to get the first value from the first function.

So when I type 1 , the program should ask to enter a value, and then when I type 2, the program should just show my value.

I don't see why it keeps asking for a value. What am I doing wrong?

note : when i delete this line from yyy

```
self.xxx()
```

i see this error

```
'MyClass' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: Just don't call `self.xxx()` in `yyy`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille he show this : 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: You're supposed to have entered the value before by typing `1`, which would call `obj.xxx`, which would set this attribute.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes but why i see the error idk i have see all the tuto and i can't find any solution

Comment: You'll only see that error if you haven't called `xxx` before you call `yyy`.

Comment: @chepner but when i call xxx he told me to inter a value this is the problem . i want when i click 2 i see just the value that i have entred in  fonction 1 please help

Comment: Right now, `xxx` is the *only* way you have to set the value of `self.a` (unless you assign value to it outside a method). It's not clear what you want, but it probably involves rewriting either or both of the methods.

Comment: Consider editing your post clarifying your question and correcting obvious misspellings. Also, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the value of xxx function and you must return the value from self.a

```
class MyClass(object):
def xxx(self):
    self.a = int(input("entre a value :"))
    return self.a
def yyy(self):
    xxx_func = self.xxx()
    print (xxx_func)

obj = MyClass()
n = int(input("choose a number : "))
if (n == 1) :
    obj.xxx()
elif (n == 2):
    print(n)
else:
    print ("error")
```

Take a look at this link from the official python documentation if you have doubts or any troubles while using the`class` statement.

[9. Classes — Python 3.7.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) *Python 3*

[9. Classes — Python 2.7.16 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) *Python 2*

Comment: when i click 2 , he still ask my to entre a value . i want when i click 2 i get just the value of my variable .

Comment: i don't want so show n variable . i want to show to value entered in the first fonction .

Comment: What you are asking is not possible, because self.a is defined by user,  if you enter the number 2 on the n input, you can only get `n` value, but if you want to get `self.a` value from `yyy` function, you will get that error, because `self.a` is not defined yet, `self.a` will be defined once you call xxx function, and the user input get stored on `self.a`, `self.a` is a local variable, if you want to get the value of `self.a` outside the function, you will get an error, check [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables)

Comment: in c language this thing is possible , but in pythone no , thanks now i understand

Comment: In C language it is even more strict to declare variables, so you should, in order to get what you want acomplished, declare every variable first, otherwise you have some dirty code